# Minor wanting to start a web development business

Tags: usa, web-development

I am a minor, and I would like to start a business doing freelance web development. I know nothing about freelance work, so naturally I have a ton of questions:

- What do I need to make my business legal? (business license, etc.)
- How much should I charge? I have skills in all the regular things - HTML, CSS, JS, PHP, SQL
- How should I make a customer aware that I am a minor? Do I even need to?
- What do I need to pay taxes on?
- What are the typical freelance... Well, I can't think of the word for it, but like the things that most freelance people do, like how to manage payment from the customer, contracts, legal stuff, etc

I am based in the United States - Colorado, specifically

I have already done research, but I'm having a hard time finding information.

Comment: Hi Nate, welcome to Freelancing.SE! I see a lot of these questions has been asked already on here, and would suggest reading those ones first. As well, if you read [ask], it does ask to keep separate questions separate - you are essentially asking 5 major questions in one, which is not encouraged on the StackExchange Network. Once you read some other questions (try sorting by popular votes first, and reading those ones), I invite you to come back here, and ask about a *specific* problem that makes up one single questions for us to answer. Hope this helps! Questions, see [chat] or [meta] :)

Comment: Be aware, in the US minors can **not** enter legal agreements. You **can't** own a business as a minor.  You **must** be a legal adult to own a business. Your desire has little to do with anything. If you can't **legally** be held responsible, I'm uncertain how many legitimate businesses would hire you even if you're web dev kung fu was fantastic.

Comment: @Nate Most freelancers are not even "inc.." or registered. But you'll need an adult to back you up anyway. The other issue is that you can sign contracts but they can easily be void if you're a minor, so again... it'd be better with an adult to co-sign. One major issue is the credit card that you'll need for essential services for your freelance projects. I still encourage you to get started, lot of entrepreneurs started before they were 18, with some help. Don't let others stop you. Here is a link with info https://www.sba.gov/blogs/6-things-you-need-know-about-starting-business-minor